# Will an event that takes a long time to finish change the value of a "Mutable variable"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, mutable

I have a large `for` loop (somewhere around 1000 iterations) in which an image URL from an object is loaded and, if it loads correctly, the object added to an array.  My question is, because of the asynchronous nature of Javascript, if the image loading takes a long time, will the `for` loop continue iterating, and thus change the index value, and thus load the wrong item into the array. I get a warning from my editor that `Mutable variable is accessible from closure` in the following code:

```
function createArray(data){
    var entries = data['entries'];
    for (var k = 0, j = entries.length; k < j; k++) {
            if (entries[k].type = 'image') {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function(){
                    validArray.push(entries[k]); //Here is where it is added to array. This [k] is the mutable value - wondering if the image takes a long time to load, if [k] will be incremented 
                };
                img.onerror = function(){
                    console.log('error: bad image source');
                };
                img.src = entries[k].url;
            } else {
                console.log('Not an image');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not an issue of timing.  All your array elements will have the same item (the last value in `entries`).  See @McGarnagle's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, the variable `k` will likely have changed by the time the callback is executed.  There is a simple solution though -- wrap the function in a closure.  That way you can create a local copy of `k`, or more meaningfully, a local copy of entries[k]:

```
img.onload = (function(entry) {
    return function(){
        validArray.push(entry); 
    };
})(entries[k]);
```

Or if you prefer to simplify the syntax, you can write a helper function like "getAddFunction":

```
var getAddFunction = function(entry) {
    return function() {
        validArray.push(entry); 
    };
};
```

And then just:

```
img.onload = getAddFunction(entries[k])
```

Comment: Love it. I should have known.  I realize syntactically they do the same thing but is there one format that is more accepted than the other?

Comment: Also, do I need to be concerned with the time between setting `img.src` and the time that `img.onload` fires (i.e. could the variable `k` be changed in the time frame as well?

Comment: @Startec I would recommend the latter -- more readable, and no real downside.

Comment: @Startec the `img.src` assignment is fine -- that is guaranteed to run before the next iteration of the loop.  It's only the callbacks that you have to worry about.